# Using pointers within structure for assigning string

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to assign a string to a pointer which is in the structure. Even though, I am able to initialise the string to pointer successfully, when I try to use the string(access the pointer), I get some random values. How should I solve the problem. Following is my code:

```
typedef struct
{

    uint8_t LOG_ID;
    uint8_t timestamp;
    uint8_t loglength;
    uint8_t checksum;
    uint8_t *payload;

} Log;
Log LB_t;

void main(){
LB_t.LOG_ID=1;
    LB_t.timestamp=3;
    LB_t.loglength=17;
    LB_t.checksum=89;

LB_t.payload="LED initialised";
log_item(&LB_t,17);
}
void log_item(uint8_t *logptr,uint8_t length){
    while(length!=0){
    CB_buffer_add_item(tx,*logptr);
    length=length-1;
logptr++;
    }
}
```

Is there any alternate way in which I can access the pointer?

Comment: `main()` returns `int`. `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to exist, nor to be compatible with `char` (i.e. a "string"). Please format your code properly if you expect others to read it. And please provide examples of input and output data.

Comment: why is `payload` not `char*`. Why is `log_item` arg not of type `Log`? What is CB_buffer_add_item

Comment: @underscore_d This looks like it could be embedded, in which case `void main()` is OK.

Comment: Where do you try to access the string? It looks like you're trying to manually reinvent the wheel of `offsetof()`. Is that right? It usually doesn't end well for people who try it.

Comment: Why do you pass `17`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I get it , you expect 'payload' to be inside the struct. Its not, just the pointer. You need to do this

```
typedef struct
{

    uint8_t LOG_ID;
    uint8_t timestamp;
    uint8_t loglength;
    uint8_t checksum;
    uint8_t payload[100];

} Log;
```

and then

```
strncpy(LB_t.payload, "LED initialised", 100);
```

you probaly want to make the 100 a const or #define somehwere. And change yr 17 to sizeof(Log)

Comment: is there any way apart from string copy function to do the above operation, beacause I am not allowed to use string.h library

Comment: use memcpy or write your own strncpy function that loops over the character array one byte at a time

Comment: `payload` should be an array of `char`.